# Should a Flink pipeline fail if checkpointing fails?

Tags: flink-streaming

As far as I know checkpoint failure should be ignored and retried with potentially larger state. I had this situation

- hdfs went into a safe mode b'coz of Name Node issues
- exception was thrown

  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category WRITE is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
  ..................

  at org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem.mkdirs(HadoopFileSystem.java:453)
      at org.apache.flink.core.fs.SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.mkdirs(SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.java:111)
      at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStreamFactory.createBasePath(FsCheckpointStreamFactory.java:132)
- The pipeline came back after a few restarts and checkpoint failures, after the hdfs issues were resolved.

I would not have worried about the restart, but it was evident that I lost my operator state. Either it was my kafka consumer that kept on advancing it's offset between a start and the next checkpoint failure ( a minute's worth ) or the the operator that had partial aggregates was lost. I have a 15 minute window of counts on a keyed operator

I am using ROCKS DB and of course have checkpointing turned on.

The questions thus are

- Should a pipeline be restarted if checkpoint fails ?
- Why on restart did the operator state did not recreate ?
- Is the nature of the exception thrown have to do with any of this b'coz suspend and resume from a save point work as expected ?
- And though I am pretty sure, are operators like the Window operator stateful by drfault and thus if I have timeWindow(Time.of(window_size, TimeUnit.MINUTES)).reduce(new ReduceFunction(), new WindowFunction()), the state is managed by flink ?

Answer (score 1):

That is depend upon your program style.
Suppose after getting the conformation from check point function..Your program may be working.

Without checkpoint conformation if your writing program , it will not affected your pip lining.

Further Clarification

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/internals/stream_checkpointing.html